# простой бот телеграм, после добавления в группу просто перестает работать

Tags: c#, winforms, telegram-bot

Написал бота на шарпе, все работало. Как только решил добавить в группу посмотреть, будет ли он там работать, он перестал отвечать.

Заметил, что у него нет доступа к сообщениям из группы и удалил его оттуда, но после этого он перестал отвечать даже в личные сообщения.

Перезагрузил приложение, работать не стало. Решил для теста написать еще одного, до ужаса простого, чтобы точно никаких проблем не было.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var client = new TelegramBotClient("BotApi");
            client.StartReceiving(upd, err);
        }

        private Task err(ITelegramBotClient arg1, Exception arg2, CancellationToken arg3)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        async static Task upd(ITelegramBotClient arg1, Update arg2, CancellationToken arg3)
        {
            await arg1.SendTextMessageAsync(arg2.Message.Chat.Id, "Hi");
            MessageBox.Show(arg2.Message.Chat.Id.ToString());
        }
```

Само собой вместо BotApi реальный Апи. Что не пробовал, после добавления в группу он перестает хоть как-либо реагировать. Возможно, какая то проблема из-за того, что все происходит в Виндовс Форме.

Работать не начинает, даже если удалить из группы. В коде после добавления ничего не менял. Если удалить все и сделать заново, начинает работать, но как только добавить в группу (и даже если удалить его оттуда потом) все ломается и больше не работает.

Comment: Увидел ваш комментарий, понял что не понял вопрос и бесполезность ответа. Чтож, я пытался.

Comment: Проверяйте, все ли асинхронные задачи вы ожидаете, все ли исключения обрабатываете. Исправить код который видите только вы, можете только вы.

Comment: И все же взял из вашего коментария и что-то новое, спасибо _)